# Looking for Best Practice / Most Efficient Large SQL UPDATE / INSERT

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I am looking for the best means of achieving a large data update / insert in SQL. My particular case is using MySQL 5.6, but in theory the version of SQL isn't so important.

I am downloading a large CSV file, filled with data which I need to dump into a MySQL Table. My application parses the CSV and prepares to be inserted into the database.

I need the table to be an exact replica of the data (CSV) that comes in each time, not adding every time to the end. I am looking for the best way of achieving this.

To my current SQL capabilities, I thought it might be best to simply truncate the table each time and populate it with the data as it comes through, but I am now unsure whether that is better than indexing a column and using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

My question/s are as follows:

- Is it best to truncate and then insert the data on an empty table, or better to find the data differences and use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` to update only the rows where the application has found a data discrepancy
- Either way after this, is it then best to format individual SQL `UPDATE` / `INSERT` queries per row of data and send them to the server. Or is it better to format a very large query with all data in it, or possibly split that larger query into something more manageable so as to not let the server time out.

There are approximately 100k rows in the table that is coming through. Currently, I am truncating the table before running any INSERTs. I then split the rows into 10 different sets, and run 10 large `INSERT` queries against the database. My only concern is that I do not know enough about table locking and am unsure as to whether splitting these actually achieves anything significant.

The reason I am here asking this is because the database usage graphs in my monitor are showing spikes, and I thought maybe it would be better to have a steadier data flow and am trying to figure out how to achieve such.

[image: DB Disk Writes]

I understand that this is just disk writes, but all graphs look more or less the same, with lots of spikes and no consistency.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to go with [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), wherein you can import either "structure and data" or "data" in .CSV format into the table.   It is advised to first import the table structure first and then import the data for an efficient import. You can also specify chunks of data to be imported at a time inorder to avoid connection loss.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mathew. I actually already use MySQL workbench which has the same functionality in importing CSV's to a table but the procedure needs to be automatic and built into a program for end users :)

All good though, Michael below (marked as answer) gave me exactly what I needed. Upvote for useful suggestion anyway for you though thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) instead of insert/update operations when you are working with large `csv` files. You didn't mention what parsing operations you are performing before the insert, some of them might be possible with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` alone. `TRUNCATE` the table before the statement.

Here's an example for a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement that ignores the first line (header) and replaces comma values for a price field while loading the data, just as an example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table 
CHARACTER SET UTF8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(col1,col2,col3,colN, @price) 
SET price = REPLACE(@price,',','.');
```

As you've said you need all the fields from the csv, simply pass the column's names here

```
(col1,col2,col3,colN, @price)
```

in the same order as they are in your csv. This will be way faster than any insert statement you could write.

To enable `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, you need to set the connection flag when establishing the connection to the database (within the options directly in the connection options, it doesn't work after), e.g. using php PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . env('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' . $database, env('DB_USERNAME'), env('DB_PASSWORD'), 
               [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1]);
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks Michael I'll give that a try :)